# How to emulate 1970s studio-style photo?

Tags: film

How can I emulate a 70's studio-style photo for a shortfilm?

Some new photos with same style, more or less:

[image]

Here is some tests I ve been making for a videoclip:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: what tools do you want to use? just photoshop?. why the film tag, will you try to work it on analog film or with digital tools. if you want to use digitale tools like photoshop film is a wrong tag.

Comment: Can't quite tell how these photos are supposed to represent 70's style studio photos (which is very broad by itself). Do you have examples to show what you mean with this style?

Comment: I would like to achieve this type of light and texture in the video using a digital camera. This type of old school, but at the same time colorful style.

Comment: have you trialled any free LUT's that get you close to what you want? Perhaps thats your starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @AbdulQuraishi, but I am trying to put more effort in the preparation of the set more than in the pospo/edit.

Answer (score -1):

Light it the way studio photos in the 1970s were lit.

**Getting  the light right is 90% of the battle.**

Then all you need to do in post processing is create raw development profiles that emulate the responses of color films used by portrait studios in the 1970s.